# Return time of interactions (reply, mention) in users in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, twitter

Suppose we have 3 tables: tweet, users, tweet_mentusers, where tweet.user_id = users.id and tweet.id = tweet_mentusers.tweet_id.

A representation of the table could be:

```
    tweet                users                    tweet_mentusers                   

id   | user_id           id                       tweet_id | mentuser_id       
----- --------          -------                   --------- ------------
11   |  1                 1                         11     |  3
12   |  2                 2                         12     |  4
13   |  2                 2                         13     |  4
14   |  1                 1                         14     |  3
15   |  1                 1                         15     |  5
16   |  2                 2                         16     |  4
```

So, I am trying to identify the interactions among those users.
My query in PostgreSQL is:

```
select id1, id2 
from (
      select tweet.id as tweetid, tweet_mentusers.mentionedusers_id as id1 
      from tweet 
      inner join tweet_mentusers on tweet.id = tweet_mentusers.tweet_id
      group by 2, 1
      ) a inner join
     (
     select users.id as id2, tweet.id as tweetid 
     from users 
     inner join tweet on users.id = tweet.user_id 
     group by 1, 2
     ) b on a.tweetid = b.tweetid
```

So the query returns the ids of people tweeting and the people they mention. 
However, I would like to know if there is a way to return only unique interactions and maybe the count of the times the interactions occur, since this query returns all interactions. 
Until now I am trying it a lot with some combinations, but I have no luck. 
If you have any propositions I would be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of interactions by grouping the result of your query by a pair (`mentioned`, `tweeter`):

```
select mentioned, tweeter, count(*)
from (
    select id1 mentioned, id2 tweeter
    from (
        select tweet.id as tweetid, tweet_mentusers.mentuser_id as id1 
        from tweet 
        inner join tweet_mentusers on tweet.id = tweet_mentusers.tweet_id
        group by 2, 1
        ) a 
    inner join (
        select users.id as id2, tweet.id as tweetid 
        from users 
        inner join tweet on users.id = tweet.user_id 
        group by 1, 2
        ) b 
    on a.tweetid = b.tweetid
    ) sub
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;

 mentioned | tweeter | count 
-----------+---------+-------
         3 |       1 |     2
         4 |       2 |     3
         5 |       1 |     1
(3 rows)
```

However, your query is unnecessarily complicated. Try this one:

```
select mentuser_id mentioned, user_id tweeter, tweet_id
from tweet_mentusers m
join tweet t
on m.tweet_id = t.id

 mentioned | tweeter | tweet_id 
-----------+---------+----------
         3 |       1 |       11
         4 |       2 |       12
         4 |       2 |       13
         3 |       1 |       14
         5 |       1 |       15
         4 |       2 |       16
(6 rows)
```

and finally:

```
select mentioned, tweeter, count(*)
from (
    select mentuser_id mentioned, user_id tweeter, tweet_id
    from tweet_mentusers m
    join tweet t
    on m.tweet_id = t.id
    ) sub
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;

 mentioned | tweeter | count 
-----------+---------+-------
         3 |       1 |     2
         4 |       2 |     3
         5 |       1 |     1
(3 rows)
```

Comment: wow! thank you! you are great! I am still learning all these stuff, so I have to make them simpler as well :) Thank a lot really!